# MySQL join multiple tables error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I struggle to use join on multiple tables. When I try to do this:

```
SELECT `absences`.*, `employee`.*, `type`.*
FROM `absences`, `type`
 LEFT JOIN `login`.`employee` ON `absences`.`employee_FK` = `employee`.`employee_ID`
```

I get this:

```
Unknown column 'absences.employee_FK' in 'on clause'
```

'absences.employee_FK' exists in my DB.

I want to display the user data and the type of the absence. How can I do that? I dont understand joins too well yet.

[image]

Comment: What's follows `left join` show be a table name. So, is `login`.`employee` a table name? That means `login` is a database name and `employee` is a table in `login`. What's the output of `show create table absences` is like? Maybe you misspelled the name of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your just trying to join two tables, because you don't have a join condition for the `type` table in your query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM absences
LEFT JOIN employee ON absences.employee_FK = employee.employee_ID
```

If you want to join to the `type` table too:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM absences
LEFT JOIN type ON absences.type_FK = type.type_ID
LEFT JOIN employee ON absences.employee_FK = employee.employee_ID
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked I think I had a logical error. There was no need to join type too I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select all the tables for using the JOIN condition.

The example goes like this:

```
SELECT `employee.*`, `absences.*`, `type.*`

FROM `employee`

JOIN `absences`

ON `employee`.`employee_ID` = `absences`.`employee_FK`

JOIN `type` 

ON `absences`.`type_FK` = `type`.`type_ID`

JOIN `on_off`

ON `on_off`.`on_off_ID` = `employee`.`on_off_FK`;
```

You can modify the query as per your requirement.

Comment: @Jens.. Thanks for editing. I should have corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use join for all tables:

```
SELECT `absences`.*, `employee`.*, `type`.*
FROM `absences`
 JOIN `type` on `absences`.`type_fk` = `type`.`type_ID`
 LEFT JOIN `login`.`employee` ON `absences`.`employee_FK` = `employee`.`employee_ID`
```

Comment: Getting  "Unknown column 'absences.type_FK' in 'on clause'  again".

Answer (score 0):

You can work on the script below. Add Where clause at the end if necessary. Not tested...

```
SELECT * from absences a
inner join type t on (t.typeID = a.type_FK)
inner join employee e on (e.employee_ID = a.employee_FK)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for

```
select * from `absences` a
    left outer join `employee` e on e.`employee_ID` on a.`employee_FK`
    left outer join `type` t on t.`type_ID`=a.`type_FK`
    left outer join `on_off` o on o.`on_off_ID`=e.`on_off_FK`
```